# "Unsupported parameters for (file) module: creates"

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I created a ansible playbook which creates a directory and then copy files to that directory. Then to provide idempotency i used args and creates, but it is givig me below error:

```
 FAILED! => {"changed": false, "checksum": "691713a12a3c088b216c14832a0c2682c88d205d", "failed": true, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (file) module: creates. Supported parameters include: attributes,backup,content,delimiter,diff_peek,directory_mode,follow,force,group,mode,original_basename,owner,path,recurse,regexp,remote_src,selevel,serole,setype,seuser,src,state,unsafe_writes,validate"}
```

I checked the documentation for File and it does not tell anything about args. Can someone please suggest what need to be done to provide idempotency for directory creation and copying files ?? Below is my code:

```
hosts: all
become: yes
become_method: sudo
vars_files:
  roles/bootstrap/vars/main.yml

tasks:
 name : Creating Directory /opt/app/{{ appversion }}
 file: path=/opt/app/{{ appversion }} state=directory
 args:
  creates: "/opt/app/{{ appversion }}"

 name: Copying the Upgradce Build
 copy:
  src: "/tmp/app-{{ appversion }}.tar.gz"
  dest: /opt/app/{{ appversion }}
 args:
  creates: "/opt/app/{{ appversion }}/app-{{ appversion }}.tar.gz"
```

Answer (score 1):

Idempotency is already built into the `file` and `copy` modules.  You do not need to add anything to the play.

Comment: just now i tested... it actually is built in !! thanks a lot :)